# External manipulation of Vue filelds

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, interaction

I am looking to use custom Javascript to interact with form fields tied with Vue framework. The form appears in a WordPress theme search page (https://wilcity.com/search-without-map/)

1. Autoselect the region value (this I can perform using the JS below)

```
markerCityName = "Atlanta";
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("wilcity-select-2 select2-hidden-accessible")[0].options.length; i++) {

  if (document.getElementsByClassName("wilcity-select-2 select2-hidden-accessible")[0].options[i].innerText == markerCityName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("wilcity-select-2 select2-hidden-accessible")[0].selectedIndex =
      document.getElementsByClassName("wilcity-select-2 select2-hidden-accessible")[0].options[i].index;

    triggerEvent(document.getElementsByClassName("select2-selection select2-selection--single")[0], 'focus');
    triggerEvent(document.getElementsByClassName("select2-selection select2-selection--single")[0], 'keydown');
    triggerEvent(document.getElementsByClassName("wilcity-select-2 select2-hidden-accessible")[0], 'change');

  }
}
```

2. Selected value participates in the search without having to manually select it from the form interface.

   (i) After the javascript runs and selects "Atlanta" in the region drop down.
   (ii) Select any other field in the form for search to be executed.
   (iii) you will notice this search did not take into account the pre-select region value "Atlanta"

I am unable to do (2). The autoselected value is not sent in post when form value changes, and the autoselected value is not picked up.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Selected value participates in the search without having to manually select it from the form interface"?  It's not clear to me what you intend by that.

Comment: The formatting was such an issue for the code snipped in my Chrome browser. I was trying to format it correctly for readability.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: @DanielBeck, I added details on (2)

Comment: @DanielBeck Thought so. It just took me several glances to notice.

Comment: @MorganJanjuaCrane  You're doing a lot of direct DOM manipulation in the code above, which is very much not how Vue is designed to work; normally you would do this with a `v-model` on your select field, then changing its selected value is just a matter of changing the v-model data.  You haven't shown enough context for the above code for us to know why the search isn't working, but I would guess that it's running based on the component's internal data, so doesn't know about the DOM manipulation you did here.

Comment: @DanielBeck, the reason is that I am writing a workaround on top of someone's else wordpress theme code. I do not want to update the core theme code, and want to interact with this VUE bound dropdown field in a way that it align wit hthe underlying data model when submitted in ajax POST.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly: the search form is done in Vue, but you're trying to write code outside of Vue which will change one of the Vue component's values?

Comment: @DanielBeck correct. I have done it in a similar fashion on another form. Apparently the "keyup" event trigger and captured values to be submitted there. But, here, the same technique isnt working to capture and update the VUE model.

So, basically, im looking for a hack here.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the DOM directly won't work, as you've discovered, because Vue doesn't know about those changes and is still working based on its internal state.  You need to modify Vue's underlying data model instead.

Every Vue component's root DOM element will have a `__vue__` property attached, which you can use to access and modify the component's internal state from outside:

```js
// Set up a Vue component with some data in it:
Vue.component('child', {
  data() {
    return {
      foo: 'Data from inside Vue'
    }
  },
  template: '<div id="component">{{foo}}</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});

// now outside Vue:
document.getElementById('component').__vue__.$data.foo = "Updated value from outside vue"
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child></child>
  
</div>
```

Use of the `__vue__` property isn't officially supported, as far as I know, but [Vue's author says it's safe to use](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5621):

> the official devtool relies on it too, so it's unlikely to change or break.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this out.